# Login to telnet server with nodejs, authenticate and run command

Tags: express, nodes, telnet

My client has installed a MicroTik router I want to use to send sms messages.
It comes with a telnet server I can connect to.
I tested it and it works , using the telnet command on Linux systems. I telnet to the ip at the specified port, and then it prompts me for the login - username and password. After authentication, I run

```
 /tool sms send usb1 "[celnumber]" message="[message]"
```

I have found this node package : [node-telnet-client](https://github.com/mkozjak/node-telnet-client)

I configured it, and ran the example on their page. 
The thing is the on ready callback never triggers, not to mention the connection closes immediately. Not only that, I do not understand how to use the prompt, since the documentation is lacking in this sense, and my non-existent experience with telnet servers is not helping me either.

So what I really need is a good example regarding how to:

- login to telnet server
- run command after authentication

from a nodejs server. I can provide extra information if need be.

Thanks

***Edit : 
My solution...***

I ran node-expect to run an expect script . For example...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var PORT = 4000;

app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

app.post('/sms', function (req, res) {
    var phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber,
        message = req.body.message,

    var isWin = require('os').platform().indexOf('win') > -1;

    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;


    if(isWin) {
        console.error('CANNOT USE THIS FROM A WINDOWS HOST');
        res.status(500).send('Only works on Linux systems with the <expect> command line script.')
    }
    if(typeof phoneNumber === 'string' && typeof message === 'string') {
        if(__CommandExists('expect')) {
            __RUNCMD('expect', ['sms.exp', phoneNumber, message]);
            res.status(200).send('Request sent !');
        } else {
            res.status(500).send('<expect> required to be installed on the host machine !');
        }
    } else {
        res.status(500).send('Required parameters : phoneNumber [string] and message [string].');
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('SMS app running on port ' + PORT);
})

function __RUNCMD(cmd, args, callback ) {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var child = spawn(cmd, args);
    var resp = "";
    child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) {
        resp += buffer.toString()
    });
    child.stdout.on('end', function() { 
        if(callback) {
            callback (resp) 
        }
    });
}

function __CommandExists(command) {
    var commandExistsSync = require('command-exists').sync;
    return commandExistsSync(command);
}
```

And the expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
set timeout 20 

#set hostName [lindex $argv 0] 
#set port [lindex $argv 1] 
#set userName [lindex $argv 2] 
#set password [lindex $argv 3] 
#set mobil [lindex $argv 4] 
#set mesaj [lindex $argv 5] - aici e cu problema, sau restul argumentelor formează mesajul... 

set phoneNumber [lindex $argv 0];
set message [lindex $argv 1];

spawn telnet [ip] [p] // defaults to 2323 

expect "Login:" 
send "yourusername\r" 
expect "Password:" 
send "yourpass\r" 

#interact 

expect "\[sms@MikroTik\] > " 
send "\/tool sms send usb1 \"$phoneNumber\" message=\"$message\"\r" 

#interact 

expect "\[sms@MikroTik\] >" 
send "\r" 
send "quit\r" 

expect eof
```

Of course, you need to add your security and what-not.

Comment: Hi, Do you find any solution to this. because i have similar requirement. Please share if you have any solution

Comment: Hello.
I used node-expect to run an expect script. Hit a route, run the expect script, get the return.

https://github.com/mjackson/expect
https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html

Expect only works on Linux afaik. I edited my question.